# How to change default eclipse IDE to new version IDE in Ubuntu?

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, ubuntu-16.04

I had installed eclipse some few months back in my Ubuntu machine.

so if I type command

```
eclipse
```

Eclipse IDE of version 3.8 loads.

But now I have downloaded 'eclipse mars' version, unzipped  it and its present in folder location

```
/home/rahul/Installers/Eclipse-Mars/eclipse
```

I have also changed the content of file "eclipse.desktop" present in path

```
/usr/share/applications
```

to

```
 eclipse.desktop                                                                                                                      
 [Desktop Entry]
 Type=Application
 Name=Eclipse
 Comment=Eclipse Integrated Development Environment
 Icon=/home/rahul/Installers/Eclipse-Mars/eclipse/icon.xpm
 Exec=/home/rahul/Installers/Eclipse-Mars/eclipse/eclipse
 Terminal=false
 Categories=Development;IDE;Java;
```

But still if I type command "eclipse" it load the old Eclipse IDE i.e. 3.8 version.

Please tell me how do I fix it?

Comment: Deinstall the old Eclipse and put `/home/rahul/Installers/Eclipse-Mars` into the PATH?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all try to get path of you existing eclipse by bellow command.

> which eclipse

if it is /usr/bin/eclipse

> mv /usr/bin/eclipse /usr/bin/eclipse.old

then

> ln -s /home/rahul/Installers/Eclipse-Mars/eclipse/eclipse /usr/bin/eclipse

OR

> EPATH=`which eclipse`; mv $EPATH "$EPATH.old"; ln -s /home/rahul/Installers/Eclipse-Mars/eclipse/eclipse $EPATH